# style option breaking paperclip

Tags: paperclip

In my gemfile i have `gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"` 
and `gem "cocaine", "~> 0.5.1"` (Other questions that report cocaine broke paperclip have been fixed in this version)
In my model `has_attached_file :photo , :styles => { :thumb => "32x32#" }`
In my development.rb `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/user/local/bin"`

I get an `Photo Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError` error when I try and upload.

If however I change my model to `has_attached_file :photo` removing the style attribute everything works fine. I need to be able to resize my images though, why is the style attribute breaking my uploads?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) installed.

When paperclip tries to create a thumbnail, it needs ImageMagick to resize the image. Without the **:styles,** paperclip just saves the original image and ImageMagick is not needed.